# mapply with function that takes previously computed output as input

Tags: r, mapply

I am not sure how to do this efficiently in R:

```r
B <- matrix(0,p,L+1)
  for(jj in 1:L){
    B[,jj+1] <- enet(y, X, B[,jj], lamgrid[jj+1], alpha, printitn) # enet returns a p-dim vector
  }
```

I tried to use mapply, but I cannot figure out how to pass the recently computed B[,jj] as an argument.

```r
B[,2:] <- mapply(function(b,l)<- enet(y, X, b, l, alpha, printitn), ???, lamgrid[2:])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapply` doesn’t do this, it’s a generalised `map`. The algorithm you need is known as a *scan* or [prefix (or cumulative) sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum). Unfortunately it isn’t built into R (except in [the specific case of an actual sum and product](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html)), and I’m not aware of a mainstream package implementing the operation either.

Either way, the loop you’ve written may not be very elegant but its efficiency isn’t an issue, and using a scan algorithm wouldn’t make it more efficient.